# Unable to export an AIR release build with icons specified in the app.xml

Tags: air, packaging

I keep getting an error when I try to export a release AIR build:

Error creating AIR file:Foo-app.xml: error 303: Icon /C:/Users/Fred/AppData/Local/Temp/assets/icon_16.png is missing from package

Directory looks like:

```
Foo/
  src/
  assets/
  bin/
```

app-xml specifies the icons as

```
<icon>
  <image16x16>assets/icon_16.png</image16x16>
  <image32x32>assets/icon_32.png</image32x32>
  <image48x48>assets/icon_48.png</image48x48>
<!-- <image128x128>assets/icon_128.png</image128x128>    -->
</icon>
```

I've tried moving the assets/ directory under the bin/ and putting a parent pronoun (..) in the tag.

I embed the images in the application thus:

```
        [Embed(source="../assets/biocurious_logo.png")]
        public var applicationIconClass : Class;

        [Embed(source="../assets/biocurious_eye_16_16.png")]
        public var applicationIcon16Class : Class;

        [Embed(source="../assets/biocurious_eye_32_32.png")]
        public var applicationIcon32Class : Class;

        [Embed(source="../assets/biocurious_logo_48_48.png")]
        public var applicationIcon48Class : Class;

        [Embed(source="../assets/biocurious_logo_128_128.png")]
        public var applicationIcon128Class : Class;
```

The compiler does not complain that it cannot find the files.

I've done the indicated searches here and using Google in general. I have no idea what to try next.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a couple things jump out at me on this.

1. If the image is embedded in the application, are you also trying to use it somehow in the deployment / installation (ie desktop icon)? If not, then you shouldn't have to even reference it as part of the deployment package - this will have already been included in the swf.
2. The image name in the application.xml is different than the source image you have referenced in code, and also a different source-path to it (ie ../assets and assets/).

If neither one of these leads you down the right path, you can always validate that the .air file has the sources in it by opening it in a standard compression program (.air is a lot like a .swc in the sense that it's nothing more than a zipped up package).

Comment: I can't create the the air (zip), let alone look inside of it.

I am confused by the relationship between embedded the image file as a resource and specifying it in the app.xml. I think the latter allows the installer to provide those image file to the OS for desktop/shortcut/dock icons. If I remove all the image tags, I get the default (red splotch) icon for the application.

Thanks for the ideas

Comment: The [Embed] / @Embed for mxml, both directly add the asset in question into the swf. SWF file format architecture consists of code (frame), and a bitmap/vector art asset (layer) - to which we generally run code against the asset. If you're familiar with Flash, embedding is analogous to directly adding it to the library so that the asset is ready to use without external loading. The application.xml is the container by which the AIR player knows what to do with the application and how to generally display it. When packaging it needs a/path/to/asset.jpg/png if you want to use that as an icon.

Comment: Mike: what is the correct path? relative to the project directory? to the src/ ? To the bin/ ?

Comment: The embed reference will be relative to a source path, while the application.xml will be relative to itself during the build/compile phase.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue when I moved the assets folder to the src folder.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution to this problem "303 app.xml icon file is missing in package"

1. create the ***assets*** folder inside ***src*** instead of application folder
2. try to put all versions of the icon sizes

   ```
   <!-- The icon the system uses for the application. For at least one resolution, 
   specify the path to a PNG file included in the AIR package. Optional. --><icon>
   <image16x16>assets/icon16.png</image16x16>
   <image32x32>assets/icon32.png</image32x32>
   <image48x48>assets/icon48.png</image48x48>
   <image72x72>assets/icon72.png</image72x72>
   <image128x128>assets/icon128.png</image128x128></icon>
   ```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1. If you embed images in Application using [Embed (source="/images/info_emb.png" )], then use the same image somewhere else in your application means it will not exists in released package.
2. Use separate images for each.